# Grub2 unable to find other OSes

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, grub2

I have Windows 7 installed on another internal harddrive. I installed Grub2 but its not recognizing any other OS other than Ubuntu. Does anyone know how to make it scan for OSes or add an OS manually? Thanks!

Comment: It should recognise it automatically - please add to your question the output from this sourceforge script: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Comment: Did you perform a `sudo update-grub` ? Did that solve the problem? If not follow fossfreedom's comment and post back the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [os-prober](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/os-prober) [image: Install os-prober]. Install it by running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

After installing, run the following command:

```
sudo os-prober
```

This will help you find the missing OS and restore them to your grub menu.